# Ignore underscores in code

Tags: support, markdown

If I do

```
<code>FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY</code>
```

like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818277/how-do-i-set-windows-related-file-attributes-in-ruby) then I get the underscores replaced with italics (at least in the preview), and I have to escape it with backslashes. I can see the logic for ordinary text, but for code? Is it because there's no other way do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indent 4 spaces!

You can also click the little code button above the editor, or press CTRL+K with the code selected to do the same.

See:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Which is linked from

- the little **[?]** icon above the editor
- the **full reference »** link in the sidebar when asking or editing

EDIT: I realized I didn't fully answer your question. For tiny code snippets you can use backtick to escape things to code `like_this_here`:

```
`like_this_here`
```

Anyway, we disable intra-word emphasis in Markdown, so what you're seeing in the preview is not in fact true in the final post.

Comment: It looks like one user has figured out how to disable intra-word emphasis in markdown: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30869 Any chance you'll use that code? It seems to be the most common preview vs. rendered bug to come up here on MSO.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is that [Javascript markdown preview doesn't match the rendered result](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/preview-should-match-the-posted-view).  For example intra_word_characters don't actually need to be escaped, even though the markdown preview implies that they do.